# VB.Net How can i make My MDI Parent form in the back of each MDI Child form will be opened?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

By Testing the code and executing the program (by opening the child form) I surprised with the main_frm being in front of the child form
 But I  want a better method to make the main form at the back and the child forms in front of the it and resize the child form to its normal size before executing 
I

I tried to hide the groupbox but to execute this idea , it will take  a much  time to both hide the groupbox located on the main form and Show it again in case of opening each child form and in case of closing them , respectively

rivate Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Branch_define_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem_Branch_define.Click

```
    ' Branch_define_Form.MdiChildren = New Branch_define_Form
    Branch_define_Form.MdiParent = Me
    Branch_define_Form.Show()

End Sub
```

So Any one would give me a better code or method to solve this annoying problem . I would be thankful very much to him ?
Also another question  I cant know why when I open any child form it looks like if I enlarged the size of child form to 200 % view .
Meaning the size before executing is different from when executing .. why this ?

Comment: There are a *lot* of existing posts about this, find them by googling "mdi form control overlaps child window".

Comment: That's right but most of them are explained in c# not vb. Net As i want..besides most of posts explain how to create mdi parent forms.. My wuestion Is how to format the form Size and font to be smaller size